# clang format shift << "\n" to separate line

Tags: c++, clang-format

When I have some c++ stringstream code that is like this

```
node_struct << filename << nodeID << "\n";
node_struct << "end" << "\n";
```

clang format will always format the line break to the next line even when the columnlimit is not hit.

```
node_struct << filename << nodeID 
            << "\n";
node_struct << "end" 
            << "\n";
```

How do I prevent such unwanted behavior?

Answer (score -1):

The rule you are asking about could be `BreakBeforeBinaryOperators`.

See https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

You can use this rule in your `.clang-format` configuration like this:

`BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None`